# Core Data (NSFetchedResultsController) crash with PFArray / PFMutableProxyArray (iOS 14)

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Have been getting many crash reports connected to Core Data since iOS 14 was released. The crashes seems to be triggered internally with PFArray when trying to access objects or sections from NSFetchedResultsController. Here are three examples:

```
 CoreData: -[_PFMutableProxyArray objectAtIndex:]
 CoreData: -[_PFArray objectAtIndex:]
 CoreData: -[_PFArray subarrayWithRange:]
```

Does anyone else experience this? Any suggestions on how to get around it? Or should I file a bug report to Apple?

Comment: I wouldn't file a bug unless you're reasonably certain that your code is correct. You haven't posted much information, so there's not much to go on as far as why your code is crashing. Crashes are far more likely to be caused by app bugs than framework bugs. That's not always the case, of course, but you should be pretty sure of your code before doubting the framework.

Comment: It is very tricky to setup a NSFetchedResultsController 
 to never crash. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55976212/why-does-nstableview-crash-when-processing-deleted-rows-as-nsfetchedresultscontr/56106309#56106309 for some guidance on setting it correctly.